# For $c<1$, let $f_c(x)=x^2+c$, determine the period-2 points?

Tags: chaos-theory

Ok so I know I need to set $$f_c^2(x)=x$$ so:
$$(x_0^2+c)^2+c = x \iff x_0^4+2cx_0^2-x_0+c^2+c=0$$
But how do I then solve this? Ok I have solved for the four set of roots, now you can see there are two roots for $c<\frac{1}{4}$ and four for $c<-\frac{3}{4}$. How do I find the hyperbolicity and therefore the nature of these points?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a computer? I don't know that there are any easy algebra tricks for this.

Comment: No I am not, I am guessing there are no period-2 point and they are just trivially the fixed points. I then have to comment on the hyperbolicity and stability of these points

Comment: Although looking at a graph, there should be 4 period-2 points for c<-1. So i'm completely lost

Comment: Hint: period-1 points also satisfy your equation.

Comment: You could also try $c=-1$ and $x_0=0$

Comment: I know they do, but what about others?

Comment: @Daniel The point is that the period-one points are _also_ roots of your equation - so they must be roots of the polynomial.  This lets you factor out a quadratic term (since there are two period-one points) from your quartic without having to go through the 'hoops' of Julien's answer to determine coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user user58697 pointed out $x_0^2 + c - x_0$ and $x_0^4+2cx_0^2-x_0+c^2+c$ are not coprime.

Indeed, $x_0$ is a fix point of $f$ $\iff f(x_0)=x_0\iff x_0^2+c-x_0=0$.

Since fix points of $f$ satisfy 
$$
f(f(x_0))=x_0
$$
as well,
then fix points are also solutions of 
$$
x_0^4+2cx_0^2-x_0+c^2+c=0.
$$
Hence, in this case you may divide $x_0^4+2cx_0^2-x_0+c^2+c$ over $x_0^2 -x_0+ c$ in order to get the polynomial $g(x)$ of (proper) period-2 points of $f$. In this case $g(x)$ is of degree two, so you may solve it.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the great answer. How then do I find out for which values of c these period-2 points are stable and non stable?

Comment: It's been a long time since I did stuff like this. Do you have any characterization of stable period (2 or not) points?

Answer (score 0):

Notice there is no $x^3$ term.

Try something of the form $(x^2+Ax+B)(x^2-Ax+D)$

$$(x^2+Ax+B)(x^2-Ax+D)=x^4+(D+B-A^2)x^2+(AD-AB)x+BD$$

So we know

$$D+B-A^2=2c$$
$$AD-AB=-1$$
$$BD=c^2+c$$

Which has solution $A=1$, $B=c+1$, and $D=c$.

So $x^4+2cx^2-x+c^2+c=(x^2+x+c+1)(x^2-x+c)$

I assume you can take it from there.